# Parsing Bitcoin binary data file with Python

Tags: python, performance, serialization, file-structure, cryptocurrency

The script parses Bitcoin database (blkXXXXX.dat) files directly from raw binary to txt human readable view. And I think about how to encrease the speed of processing.

Can anyone suggest how to improve the performance? I know that the best way to encrease performance is to write this on C or C++, but what about Python?  Also, is this style of programming is good?

Example cut from code (full code avaible [here](https://github.com/normanvolt/blockchain-parser/blob/3ca052cacd766f7006939c08b4e5b8ee55b6ea7c/blockchain-parser.py)):

```
import os
import hashlib

def reverse(input):
    L = len(input)
    if (L % 2) != 0:
        return None
    else:
        Res = ''
        L = L // 2
        for i in range(L):
            T = input[i*2] + input[i*2+1]
            Res = T + Res
            T = ''
        return (Res);

f = open('blk01234.dat','rb')
tmpHex = ''
fSize = os.path.getsize(t)
while f.tell() != fSize:
    for j in range(4):
        b = f.read(1)
        b = b.encode('hex').upper()
        tmpHex = b + tmpHex
    tmpHex = ''
    for j in range(4):
        b = f.read(1)
        b = b.encode('hex').upper()
        tmpHex = b + tmpHex
    resList.append('Block size = ' + tmpHex)
    tmpHex = ''
    tmpPos3 = f.tell()
    while f.tell() != tmpPos3 + 80:
        b = f.read(1)
        b = b.encode('hex').upper()
        tmpHex = tmpHex + b
    tmpHex = tmpHex.decode('hex')
    tmpHex = hashlib.new('sha256', tmpHex).digest()
    tmpHex = hashlib.new('sha256', tmpHex).digest()
    tmpHex = tmpHex.encode('hex')
    tmpHex = tmpHex.upper()
    tmpHex = reverse(tmpHex)
    resList.append('SHA256 hash of the current block hash = ' + tmpHex)
    f.seek(tmpPos3,0)
    tmpHex = ''
    for j in range(4):
        b = f.read(1)
        b = b.encode('hex').upper()
        tmpHex = b + tmpHex
    resList.append('Version number = ' + tmpHex)
    tmpHex = ''
#.....next part of code
f.close()
f = open('blk01234.txt','w')
for j in resList:
    f.write(j + '\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do a lot of manipulation of bytes to construct larger structures, which you then operate on. I'd suggest looking at the standard module `struct` which can do a lot of this for you in a way that is much easier to grasp.

Also, if you're going to read some bytes and then read them a second time, why not just read them into memory and operate on them twice?

Finally, your output appears to be text. Instead of `write()` why not use `print ()`?

**Update:**

Now that I'm not on a cell phone, let me expand a bit.

First, I'll point you to [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1163508/4029014) to a question on reading 32-bit values on SO. With that as a starting point, here's a function that does the same thing (plus a helper function that gets re-used below):

```
import struct # Top of file

def read_buffer(binfile, size):
    """ Read in size bytes from binfile, or else!
    """
    buffer = binfile.read(size)

    if buffer is None or len(buffer) != size:
        raise EOFError

def read_uint32_le(binfile):
    """ Reads an unsigned 32-bit, little-endian integer value from binfile.
    """
    buffer = read_buffer(binfile, 4)
    u32 = struct.unpack('<I', buffer)[0] # unpack always returns tuple
    return u32
```

With this function, I can rewrite some of your code:

```
while f.tell() != fSize:
    for j in range(4):
        b = f.read(1)
        b = b.encode('hex').upper()
        tmpHex = b + tmpHex
    tmpHex = ''
    for j in range(4):
        b = f.read(1)
        b = b.encode('hex').upper()
        tmpHex = b + tmpHex
    resList.append('Block size = ' + tmpHex)
```

Becomes:

```
while f.tell() != fSize:
    ignored = read_uint32_le(f)
    blk_size = read_uint32_le(f)
    reslist.append(f"Block size = {blk_size:08X}")
```

And the remainder benefits greatly from the fact that there's a [`bytes.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method:

```
tmpHex = ''
tmpPos3 = f.tell()
while f.tell() != tmpPos3 + 80:
    b = f.read(1)
    b = b.encode('hex').upper()
    tmpHex = tmpHex + b
tmpHex = tmpHex.decode('hex')
tmpHex = hashlib.new('sha256', tmpHex).digest()
tmpHex = hashlib.new('sha256', tmpHex).digest()
tmpHex = tmpHex.encode('hex')
tmpHex = tmpHex.upper()
tmpHex = reverse(tmpHex)
resList.append('SHA256 hash of the current block hash = ' + tmpHex)
f.seek(tmpPos3,0)
tmpHex = ''
for j in range(4):
    b = f.read(1)
    b = b.encode('hex').upper()
    tmpHex = b + tmpHex
resList.append('Version number = ' + tmpHex)
tmpHex = ''
```

Becomes:

```
buffer = read_buffer(f, 30)
hash2 = sha256(sha256(buffer)).hex().upper()
reslist.append(f"SHA256 hash of the current block hash = {hash2}")
version = struct.unpack_from('<I', buffer)[0] # returns a tuple
reslist.append(f"Version number = {version:08X}")
```

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions:

- Every single line should at least be comprehensible on its own. Single letter variables destroy that comprehension, meaning that anyone reading the code needs to read the *entire* code and mull it over for a while to even understand what it's meant to do. Something like `current_byte = file_handle.read(1)` is a lot more readable than `b = f.read(1)`.
- All the top-level code should be in either functions, methods or classes, and the file should have a `main` function, so that the pieces of this code can be understood and reused.
- Running this through at least one linter such as `flake8` and `pycodestyle` will give several tips to produce more pythonic code. For example, `return (Res);` should be written as `return res` - no parentheses or semicolon, and `snake_case` variable names.
- There are several magic values like `80` and `4` which are hard to guess the meaning of. They should be pulled out as named variables or constants.
- Instead of closing the file handle explicitly you should use a context manager like `with open(…) as file_handle:`. This ensures that the file handle will be closed even if there is an exception.
- Rather than checking whether the current position in the file is at the end you should read until reading returns nothing.
- There are assignment operators such as `//=` which can simplify some of your expressions.
- A helpful exercise for detecting "hacky" code is to add [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to it, and verifying it with `mypy` using strict settings (like not allowing `Any`). For example, it looks like the type of `b` would be `Union[byte, str]`, which is a code smell - the variable is literally used for two different *types of* things.

Comment: the problem with context manager is that it doesnt play nice with try except finally

Comment: @PirateApp You'd have to back that assertion up with some hard facts.